# How do I remove a board from an organization in Trello?

Tags: trello

I accidentally added one of my private boards to an organization and I wanted to undo that, without deleting the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a board's organization is not currently possible, thought it is on the Trello Development board: https://trello.com/card/board/change-a-board-s-organization/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4ea5e29164967eb145006f32

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your board's visibility to members and then remove the members from that board.
There is no option for removing a board from the organization, hopefully in the next build they might implement this.

Answer (score 0):

A board administrator can now change the organization of a board by doing the following:

1. Open the "Profile" of the board in question
2. Click the "change" link in the "Organization" section.
3. Select the correct organization (or "None") to make it a stand-alone board.